# Boundary and closure of a set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that a point is in the boundary of $E$ if and only if it belongs to the closure of both $E$ and its complement.

Let $\overline{E}$ denote the closure of $E$ and $E^\circ$ be the interior of $E$. Then the boundary is defined to be $\overline{E} \setminus E^\circ$.

So what I need to show is $\overline{E} \setminus E^\circ = \overline{E} \cap \overline{(S \setminus E)}$.

After looking at this link: [A point is in the boundary of $E$ if and only if it belongs to the closure of both $E$ and its complement.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350197/a-point-is-in-the-boundary-of-e-if-and-only-if-it-belongs-to-the-closure-of-bo) I am confused about how the OP concluded that he/she needed to show $S \setminus E^\circ = \overline{(S \setminus E)}$.

Could someone explain why?

Comment: Could you use $\overline{E}$ instead of $E^{-}$? It is the usual notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$Suppose that you can show that $S\setminus\int E=\cl(S\setminus E)$. Then

$$(\cl E)\setminus\int E=\big((\cl E)\cap S\big)\setminus\int E=(\cl E)\cap(S\setminus\int E)=(\cl E)\cap\cl(S\setminus E)\;,$$

which is exactly what you want.

To see where the idea comes from, note that both $(\cl E)\setminus\int E$ and $(\cl E)\cap\cl(S\setminus E)$ are subsets of $\cl E$. If $A$ is any set disjoint from $\cl E$, therefore,

$$(\cl E)\setminus\int E=(\cl E)\cap\cl(S\setminus E)\quad\text{iff}\quad A\cup\Big((\cl E)\setminus\int E\Big)=A\cup\Big((\cl E)\cap\cl(S\setminus E)\Big)\;,$$

and a clever choice of $A$ might give us sets that are easier to think about than $(\cl E)\setminus\int E$ and $(\cl E)\cap\cl(S\setminus E)$. In particular, if we let $A=S\setminus\cl E$, we can compare the set,

$$(S\setminus\cl E)\cup\Big((\cl E)\setminus\int E\Big)\;,$$

which is simply all of $S$ except $\int E$, or $S\setminus\int E$, with the set

$$(S\setminus\cl E)\cup\Big((\cl E)\cap\cl(S\setminus E)\Big)\;,$$

which is simply $\cl(S\setminus E)$, and try to show that **these** are equal.

Comment: Thank you very much! I follow the first 3 lines. It will take me sometime to digest the rest.

Comment: @Student: You’re very welcome; feel free to leave a comment if you get stuck on any of it.

Comment: Dear @BrianM.Scott I'm reading the following [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668485/proof-explanation-every-closed-subset-is-a-boundary) here on MathStack Exchange, could you give some help to understand it? I think that we need to use this question, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Math23: I see that you accepted the answer by Oliver Diaz; did that answer your questions satisfactorily?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes thanks! You are an expert in topology, I was not able to use the results so I asked for your help.